# Javascript: Closure Problem, I Guess.. or something strange?

Tags: javascript, jquery, serverside-javascript

Well, I was using *JQuery* for Ajax Post request and getting the data back.

Ajax is working fine, but:

```
coordinates = [];

$.post("ajax_markers.php",{time:time},function(result) { coordinates=result.split(','); alert(coordinates); });  // Alerts the Coordinates as Expected :)
```

But..

```
$.post("ajax_markers.php",{time:time},function(result) { coordinates=result.split(','); });

alert(coordinates); // Alerts with a Blank Box :(
```

Why is this happening ?
Both should alert with same data.. as coordinates is global to both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense.  In your second example, `alert(coordinates);` is happening right away.  Whereas `coordinates = result.split(',');` is happening relatively much later - after the request succeeds.  If you want to make the second example work, you have to wait for the coordinates to be assigned.  Something like this working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UtXgK/11/

```
var coordinates = 'no response from server yet';
$.post("/echo/json/",{json:'{"data":"one,two,three"}'},function(result) { coordinates=result.data.split(','); alert(coordinates[1]);});
setTimeout(function(){ alert(coordinates[2]); }, 5000);
```

Assuming it takes no longer than 5 seconds to return a result from your $.post.

Comment: Can we have some work around using jquery.. ??
Like we have the $(document).ready(function() {/* Stuff here */});

So, can we do it in a similar way... 

Can we have a ready function for this ajax call ???

Comment: Your approach shows an error : setTimeout('alert(coordinates);', 5000);

Error : coordinates is not defined !!

I think now it is closure problem ??

Comment: No, it is not a closure problem, you probably didn't declare coordinates (my code is just a snippet).  And yes, jQuery 1.5 introduced chaining additional event handlers. See Promise and Deferred object documentation: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: Well I have declared coordinates (Confirmed) but its showing error.
And can you give a snippet of jquery solution, as I am researching the issue but I am just a starter !

Please don't mind.. I am a novice !

Comment: I edited my post with working code and a fiddle you can play with for yourself.  Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

In this one:

```
$.post("ajax_markers.php",{time:time},function(result) { coordinates=result.split(','); });
alert(coordinates);
```

You are immediately doing the alert before the post even returns from the server.

So I would say the problem has more to do with the order of execution than the closure.

Comment: Can we have some work around using jquery.. ??
Like we have the $(document).ready(function() {/* Stuff here */});

So, can we do it in a similar way... 

Can we have a ready function for this ajax call ???

Answer (score 1):

Your `alert(coordinates);` executes before `function(result) {...}` invocation.
Welcome to the asynchronous world.

Comment: Ok.. I am trying a different approach, but that "asynchronous world" line was great !